# Using binary search wrong?

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

Probably doing something wrong? Trying to use binary search to delete an instance from a class from an array. Instances are added to an array when created, but when I delete them from the scene I want them to be deleted from the array too. Somehow binary_search is working fine with the first delete, but not when deleting a second instance.

binary_search should return true if an instance is found in the array. But it returns false, when the instance is definitely present in the array.

Here is the code I am using.

```
void Manager::eraseInstance(SomeInstance* instance) {
    cout<< " found?: " << binary_search(instanceArray.begin(), instanceArray.end(), instance) << "  instance:  " << instance;
    for (int i = 0; i < instanceArray.size(); i++) {
        cout << "  " << i << ":  " << instanceArray[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    if (binary_search(instanceArray.begin(), instanceArray.end(), instance)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < instanceArray.size(); i++) {
            if (instanceArray[i] == instance) {
                instanceArray.erase(instanceArray.begin() + (i));
                delete instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For debugging I first cout the search result, then the instance I try to erase, and then all instances present in the array.

Now my output in the console is the following:

Deleting the first instance output:

> found?: 1  instance: 05DCB358  0:  05DCAED8  1:  05DCB358  2: 
>   05DCADB8

Ok so everything is going well there, the instance is found, the instance identifier is the same as the second instance in the array. And everything is working fine.

Deleting the second instance output:

> found?: 0  instance: 05DCADB8 0:  05DCAED8  1: 05DCADB8

So the next instance I try to delete, this happens. The binary search cannot find the instance (BUT as you can see it is still present in the array as the second instance of the array). Because it returns false the instance is not deleted, even though my output confirms the instance is present, but binary_search says it is not?

Anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: Consider [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) instead of `std::binary_search`, since you can get the iterator to the actual found element back, rather than following up with a linear search.

Comment: `binary_search` requires the collection to be sorted, which doesn't seem to be true in your case, or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the point of a binary search that doesn't return the found variable?  You having to go linearly through the array to find if after `binary_search` returns true is killing any benefit you get from using a binary search.

Comment: @NathanOliver - as BoBTFish mentioned, `std::lower_bound` gives you the location of a matching element if there is one. `std::binary_search` just tells you whether a particular element is present.

Comment: @PeteBecker I get that.  I am just asking what is the point of using it if the OP is going to go through the container linearly to actually find the element.

Comment: @NathanOliver - got it, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thanks guys! I am a bit new to basic C++ functions so this is very helpful :)

Comment: @NathanOliver I kinda did that so I could search fast through the array to see if the element is present in the array before I go through the whole array ( Because I had no clue if there was a way to check if the element is present and on which iterator it can be found. I am used to working with Unreal Engine 4 where a lot of these functions are implemented in the engine, and I wasn't sure how this all works on basic C++ with no framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) assumes that collection contents are already sorted.

> **For std::binary_search to succeed, the range [first, last) must be at
>   least partially ordered**, i.e. it must satisfy all of the following
>   requirements:
>
> - partitioned with respect to element < value or comp(element, value)
> - partitioned with respect to !(value < element) or !comp(value, element)
> - for all elements, if element < value or comp(element, value) is true then !(value < element) or !comp(value, element) is also true

As you are not specifying custom comparison logic, it will use `operator<` which compares numerical values of the pointers.

Since your collection contents are this:

```
0: 05DCAED8 1: 05DCB358 2: 05DCADB8
```

they don't seem to be sorted (the last one actually has the lowest values) so `binary_search` fails.